# Database design for storing and calculating custom pricing structure

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am trying to create an e-commerce where seller can give custom billing structure.

Seller can define fields and can apply custom pricing logic on those fields. The custom logic can be either addition, subtraction, percentage or an absolute value.

Example 1:

`A` is the sum of all products

```
Packing Charge (B)  - 10% of A
Tax (C)             - 5% of (B + A)
Total cost          - A + B + C
```

Example 2:

`A` is the sum of all products

```
Registration Charge(B)   - 10% of A
Packing charge(C)        - 100
Tax(D)                   - 10% of (A + B + C)
Maintainance Charge(E)   - 200
Total cost               - A + B + C + D
```

Comment: You have not indicated what you have already considered and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: Please also post table structure. You say A is the sum of all products, so how do we get that value. Where are the custom structures defined and their format. Is maintenance charger always excluded from total cost as in example 2.